# How to map this design in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have been scratching my head to figure out how to do the mapping in the case below. On SQL level it is clear what to do, but EF mapping is greek to me a bit in this case.

**Business background**:

I would like to store data about that how area path's related to each other (parent - child), depth is only one level, it is different from that you can see in TFS.

**Design**:

I have a table where I store the area path values and there is another table where the relations are stored.

Tables, foreign keys are set up correctly on SQL level.

```
CREATE TABLE [AREAPATH] (
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  [NAME] TEXT NOT NULL,
  [FULLPATH] TEXT NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [AREAPATH_RELATIONS](
  [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  [PRINCIPAL_AREAPATH_ID] INT NOT NULL,
  [DEPENDENT_AREAPATH_ID] INT NOT NULL)
```

In SQL it results the dataset below:

```
AREAPATH
ID, NAME, FULLPATH
1 , asd, asd
2 , aad, asd\aad
3 , dsa, asd\dsa

AREAPATH_RELATIONS
ID, PRINCIPAL_AREAPATH_ID, DEPENDENT_AREAPATH_ID
1 , 1                    , 2
2 , 1                    , 3
3 , 2                    , 3
```

**The data what is needed for me is**:

- How many dependent areapaths does have the selected areapath, in SQL (SELECT * FROM AREAPATH_RELATIONS WHERE PRINCIPAL_AREAPATH_ID = 'givenAreaPathId')

**Questions**:

- Do I think correctly the AreaPath__Id -- AreaPathRelations__Principal_AreaPath_Id is one to many relation?
- Is this design correct? I feel it poor a bit, but fit for purpose.

**Update**

After working on this case for a while and seeing Erik's answer I realized that there are two important point was not emphasized enough:

- a child can have multiple parents
- a parent can have multiple child

Following this I think AreaPath table has many-to-many relation with itself. I put together a mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AreaPath>()
                .HasMany<AreaPath>(s => s.ChildAreaPathNodes)
                .WithMany(s => s.ParentAreaPathNodes)
                .Map(map =>
                {
                    map.ToTable("AREAPATH_DEPENDENCIES");
                    map.MapLeftKey("PRINCIPAL_AREAPATH_ID");
                    map.MapRightKey("DEPENDENT_AREAPATH_ID");
                });
```

It throws the error below:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:\r\n\r\nAreaPathNodeAreaPathNode: Name: The EntitySet
>   'AreaPathNodeAreaPathNode' with schema 'dbo' and table
>   'AREAPATH_DEPENDENCIES' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer
>   to a unique schema and table.

It says to me that EF generates entity sets but due to that the table mapped with itself EF wants to generates the same entity set twice. The question is that how can I tell to EF that what names should be used. It is possible to set it up?

AreaPath entity:

```
public class AreaPath
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AreaPathName { get; set; }

        public string FullAreaPath { get; set; }

        public int AreaPathTfsId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaPathNode> ChildAreaPathNodes { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaPathNode> ParentAreaPathNodes { get; set; }

        public int IsArchived { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple 1 to many (each parent can have multiple children, but a child can only have one parent), then you don't need to use a separate table to model this relationship.  You just need a ParentId in AreaPath table.  Make it nullable, and parents have null values, children point to the parent.

This does not enforce only a single level, but neither did your original design.

You should also avoid using the TEXT datatype as this is deprecated, and will probably be removed in a future version of SQL Server.  Instead, use varchar(MAX)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I think I haven't described my case properly because your statement "a child can have only one parent" is not true. A child can have multiple parents. I'm going to update my question accordingly.

Comment: @SayusiAndo No, `AREAPATH_RELATIONS` has two n-1 associations with `AREAPATH`. You should map them both. It's not a many-many mapping (with a hidden association class).